# Android - How to move together in two different tables HorizontalScrollViews?

Tags: android

I'm trying to do a kind of table, as a TableModel in java, dynamically inserting several TextViews, everything works right, but when I go to the last row, or any in the midle, of the table the header disappears leaving only the body of the table. I wish that it stays fixed on the table's top, only moves horizontally, according to the table, body, moves horizontally...
They are in separated tables and HorizontalViews....
I've tried everything and so far nothing....
Something like this, and in tableHeader and tableBody I insert rows with TextViews.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<TableLayout...>
    <TableRow ...
        <HorizontalScrollView>
        <TableLayout android:id="@+id/tableHeader>
        </TableLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
    <HorizontalScrollVie>
        <TableLayou android:id="@+id/tableBody>
        </TableLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</TableLayout>
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
<HorizontalScrollView>
<LinearLayout>
  <TextView .... (header) >
    <ScrollView>
      <TextView ... (cell) >
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: something like the above, I edited the question and put the xml.